# Shifting items in Python

Tags: indexing, variable-assignment

For the code below that's part of a loop, why does it say items are shifted 1 position to the right? (to me it looks like they are shifted to the left). Is this correct? and how?

```
lyst(j+1) = lyst(j)
```

Comment: it is one to the right because you assign to the next position `lst[ j + 1]` (on the right) what was at position `j` namely `lst[j]`.